# Getting a reference to the current instance of the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, code-behind

Let's say I have a WPF application which makes use of the MVVM pattern. The application's main window defines its data context in the XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Is it possible to get a reference to the current instance of `MainWindowViewModel` in the XAML code-behind after `InitializeComponent()`? I know this is not recommended when using MVVM but I can't figure out any other way for solving my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure:

```
var viewModel=DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
```

Just cast your DataContext to the type of your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold it in some static class and define it as a static resource.